# Flask app doesn't show image, but only its text

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a Flask application that scrapes the Amazon site depending on what the user enters. It scrapes name, price and image url. When you run the program and enter something to scrape, e.g. Samsung galaxy s23 ultra, it doesn't show the image but its text.

What can I change to show the image?

[image]

Here is the entire code:

> app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import concurrent.futures
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept-Language": "hr-HR,hr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
}

conn = sqlite3.connect('amazon_data.db', check_same_thread=False)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        name TEXT,
        price TEXT,
        image_url TEXT,
        scraping_status TEXT
    )
''')
conn.commit()

def scrape_page(product_name, page_num):
    try:
        URL = f"https://www.amazon.com/s?k={product_name.replace(' ', '+')}&crid=288NMI7Z5E2WR&qid=1702226389&sprefix={product_name.replace(' ', '%2C')}%2Caps%2C572&ref=sr_pg_{page_num}"

        response = requests.get(URL, headers=header)
        response.raise_for_status()

        web_page = response.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'lxml')

        result_container = soup.find("div", class_="s-main-slot")

        if result_container:
            boxes = result_container.find_all("div", class_="s-result-item")
        else:
            print(f"No search results found on page {page_num}")
            return [], [], []

        local_name_list = []
        local_price_list = []
        local_image_list = []

        for box in boxes:
            try:
                name_elem = box.find("span", class_="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal")
                price_elem = box.find("span", class_="a-offscreen")
                image_elem = box.find("img", class_="s-image")

                if name_elem and price_elem and image_elem:
                    name = name_elem.getText()
                    price = price_elem.getText()
                    image_url = image_elem['src']

                    local_name_list.append(name)
                    local_price_list.append(price)
                    local_image_list.append(image_url)
                    print(f"Product: {name}\nPrice: {price}\nImage URL: {image_url}\n{'=' * 30}")

            except AttributeError as e:
                print(f"Error extracting data from box on page {page_num}: {e}")
                continue

        return local_name_list, local_price_list, local_image_list

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error scraping page {page_num}: {e}")
        return [], [], []  # Return empty lists in case of an error

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product_name = request.form.get('product_name')
        name_list = []
        price_list = []
        image_list = []

        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            results = executor.map(scrape_page, [product_name] * 18, range(1, 19))

        for result in results:
            name_list.extend(result[0])
            price_list.extend(result[1])
            image_list.extend(result[2])

        if not name_list:
            return render_template('home.html', no_results=True, product_name=product_name)
        else:
            merged_list = list(zip(name_list, price_list, image_list))

            # Store the search results in the session
            session['results'] = merged_list
            session['product_name'] = product_name

            return render_template('home.html', results=merged_list, product_name=product_name)

    # Check if there are stored results in the session
    if 'results' in session:
        results = session['results']
        product_name = session['product_name']
        return render_template('home.html', results=results, product_name=product_name)

    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/delete_results', methods=['POST'])
def delete_results():
    # Clear the stored results in the session
    session.pop('results', None)
    session.pop('product_name', None)
    return redirect(url_for('home'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Amazon Scraper</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h1 class="mb-4">Amazon Scraper</h1>
        <nav class="mb-4">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Subscription</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <form method="post">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter product name" name="product_name" required>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        {% if results %}
            <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('delete_results') }}">
                <button class="btn btn-danger mb-3" type="submit">Delete Results</button>
            </form>
            <h2>Search results for '{{ product_name }}'</h2>
            <div class="row">
                {% for result in results %}
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
                        <div class="card">
                            <img src="{{ result[2] }}" class="card-img-top" alt="Product Image">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">{{ result[0] }}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">{{ result[1] }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% elif no_results %}
            <h2>No search results found for '{{ product_name }}'</h2>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The most likely problem is that the image `src` attributes are relative to Amazon's page.  Since your page has a different base URL, the links don't resolve.

Comment: The html template uses `result[2]` as the image link.  But as far as I can see, `result` only contains two items -- the product name is `result[0]` and the price is `result[1]`.  Where are you expecting `result[2]` to come from?

Comment: @JohnGordon I have edited and added result[2] in the app.py but it still doesn't show the image.

Comment: If you view the source on your app page, what are the image links?

Comment: <img src="" class="card-img-top" alt="Product Image">...the src seems to be empty

Comment: Okay, so the problem is that `image_elem['src']` is somehow empty on the amazon page.  Did the `print()` statement in the view code loop also show an empty image link?

Comment: When I built the scraper without the Flask it scraped image URLs normally. I don't what is the problem.

Comment: Figured it out. In function home I forgot to add image_list into merged_list. Everything works now. I updated the above code.